# PLSQL Trigger ORA 01403 no data found

Tags: database, oracle, triggers, ora-01403

i am making a trigger in PL-SQL to restrict employees in section/dept
     on my employee entry form i get ORA-01403: no data found .
     please anyone help me

```
create or replace trigger DEPT_STRENTH
  after insert on empmasterinfo
  for each row
DECLARE
  -- local variables here
  EMP_Count        NUMBER;
  MAX_Strength     NUMBER;
  V_Mainid         VARCHAR2(100);
  V_orgelementname VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN

--taking value from form

 V_Mainid         := :new.mainid;
  V_orgelementname := :new.orgelementname;

--Comparing values with existing 

  select d.strength
    into MAX_Strength
    from dept_strength d 

-- Master table 


 where d.Mainid = V_Mainid
     and d.orgelementname = V_orgelementname;

  select count(e.employeeid)
    into EMP_Count

-- Master table 


 from empmasterinfo e 
   where e.emp_status = 0
     and e.Mainid = V_Mainid
     and e.orgelementname = V_orgelementname;

  if EMP_Count >= MAX_Strength then

    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20101,
                            'Maximum Number of Employees in Department Reached');

  end if;

end DEPT_STRENTH;
```

Comment: When do you get this message? When the trigger fires?  More important, did you do _any_ research on the web? Just googling `ORA-01403` returns lots of helpful hits.

Comment: yes i do googly but still not get desire result. trigger fire before insert on table . when someone enter new entry in table

Answer (score 2):

This is an exercise in *debugging your code*.

Step one is to look at what you have written.  The NO_DATA_FOUND exception is thrown by a query which returns no rows.  You have two queries in your trigger.  However aggregation queries don't raise that exception, as the count will return 0.

So only one query can be hurling ORA-01403, which clearly indicates you don't have any rows in `dept_strength` that match the rows you're inserting in `empmasterinfo`.  Presumably you think you should have rows in that table, in which case you need to revisit your transactional logic.

You should probably do that anyway, as trying to enforce this sort of business rule in a trigger is a bad mistake.  It doesn't scale and it doesn't work in multi-user environments.

Comment: Since the trigger is a row-level trigger on `empmasterinfo`, I'm guessing that has something to do with the expected data not being found.  And once the current issue gets fixed, the next question will be why the trigger is throwing a mutating trigger error.

Comment: @JustinCave - Exactly so.